# Fast Sensor Object Counting With Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor

I need to count objects from 5-10 mm with using 2 sensors at arduino mega board. I have used photoelectric sensor but it's really very slow. I have to use delay(1000) commands after count an object because it's not ready to count a new item  before this period(i don't know this issue is related with sensor or with mega) . If i don't use this waiting period then it counts 2-3 items although only 1 item passes through sensor.

I need to count 2 or 3 items every second. Even i couldn't use 1 sensor properly and i need to use such 2 sensor at 1 mega board. What do ypu offer to me? Capacitive sensors are better and faster? Or is not Arduino enough fast for this project?

---

Here is my code : (I also use Ethernet Shield)

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

int sensorPin = A2;    
int ledPin = 13;      
int MachineID=2;
int sensorValue = 0;  
int dummy=0;
unsigned long TimerB=0;
unsigned long LastTime=0;
unsigned long CurrentTime =0;
unsigned long ElapsedTime =0;
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xE0 };
byte ip[] = { 10, 10, 10, 113 };
byte server[] = { 10, 10, 10, 112 }; 
//byte server[] = { 10, 10, 10, 30 }; 
EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    if (client.connect(server, 8080)) {
        Serial.println("connected");
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        LastTime = millis();    
    } else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
}

void loop()
{
    dummy=0;  
    dummy=SensorControl();
    if (dummy>0) {
       //Send data to SQL
    }
}

int SensorControl()
{
    sensorValue=0;
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    if (sensorValue>1020) {
        // Sometimes objects stays in front of sensor for a while.
        // So i have to wait until objects leave
        while (sensorValue>1020) {
            sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
        }
        //Here i have to wait 1 seconds
        TimerB=millis();
        while (millis()-TimerB <= 1000) { }
        return MachineID;  
    } else {  
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of photoelectric sensors are you using? Photodiode/receiver pairs? Infrared? Are you just checking the receiver pin with your Arduino code? Are you running any resource intensive code? The arduino should be more than capable of such slow events. EDIT: just read that it's counting 2-3 objects at once. Maybe try adjusting the threshold of your detection so it doesn't count multiple objects?

Comment: Hi @pikafu,

I don't know exactly what kind of sensor i use, i just found these sensors in spare part of a machine. But yes, i have found same sensors at internet. These are sensors which i have used :

Comment: [http://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/sensors/factory-automation-sensors/micro-photoelectric-sensors](http://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/sensors/factory-automation-sensors/micro-photoelectric-sensors)

Comment: I think it's the while loop. Try this:

    int objDetected = 0;  // flag
int detection = 1020; // detection threshold

int SensorControl2(int objDetectedFlag)
{
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
 
 if (sensorValue > detection) {
  // Sensor senses something for the first time, sets flag
  if (objDetected == 0) {
   Serial.println("object detected");
   objDetected = 1;
   return MachineID;
  }
  // Sensor senses something but object is still there
  else {
   return 0;
  }
 }
 // There is no object detected, reset the flag
 else {
  objDetected = 0;
 }
}

Comment: Probably there is noise in the sensor and it is making multiple transitions across the threshold. You want a "dead zone" between object detected and not detected.

Comment: How do you know that 'its not ready to count a new item'?

Comment: @pjc50, i read something about sensors. And it looks very cheap sensor. You can be right. SO i think may be i should use an ceramic capacitor with a resistor to block any noise. But it will be difficult to determine values of capacitor and resistor. (They can be a reason of lag)

Comment: @copper.hat, i looked many of many sensor projects which is done with Arduino and these projects use a waiting method to be ready for next reading a value from sensor. And if you look my code then i think it should run as expected. My code is enough simple. You don't think such?

Comment: My question was how do you know it is not ready to count a new item?

Comment: @ copper.hat It was my guess. If I don't put this delay then  it sends  data although there is not any item. I started to think about pull up resistors. And what do you think about my problem? Do you think sensor can read objects very fast but problem is at my design or code?

Comment: Before you start adding complexity in the form of resistors and caps, let's narrow down what the issue could be:

*Problem: Your sensor toggles multiple times when a single object passes in front of it.*

1. Your sensor is noisy so it's flipping between detected/not detected as suggested by @pjc50
2. Your Arduino is not properly detecting pin changes
3. Your detection code is broken.

*Start debugging just the sensor.* Power it with the Arduino and use a multimeter to probe the output. Does it toggle multiple times when one object passes by? What if you leave one object there for longer?

Comment: @pikafu,
It's very interesting issue. Everything works great when i try my system in my office. But when i insert this system to machine then it started to give such unwanted results. I have 7 systems which is installed to 7 machines. Only 1 machine gives such unexpected results very frequently. Other 6 machines reads 1 card as 2-3 very rarely. But as a result i want that system works exactly and properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you have solved this, but here is my thought.

To begin with, using the analog to read a signal is very inaccurate, especially that it is a photoresistor.
I would recommend adding a comparator with hysteresis so as to get a clean digital pulse, pictured below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEqgJp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has the correct values.

Then you would add an interrupt based code routine which will detect the rising edge of the signal, and stay inactive while it has something in front. Below code is done with the arduino `attachInterrupt()` for simplicity.

```
attach interrupt(0, isr, RISING); 

 volatile int flag = 0;

void isr(){
flag = 1;  // set the flag when a rising edge exists
}

void loop(){
// other code
  dummy = SensorControl2();
 if(dummy > 0){
  // do something
}

  else{
  return 0;
   }
}

void SensorControl2(){    

if(flag){

flag = 0;

return MachineID;

    }  

else{

return 0;

  }

}
```

This method produces very reliable results and it has no delay in the function. It is also accurate with objects moving rapidly because of the interrupt.

Comment: @Murat - that's fine, there is another solution for someone else who might have an issue.

Comment: Hi @RSM, i solved my problem with attaching a 10K resistor and 100nF capacitor to output(Simple RC filter circuit).

Comment: Before this correction, I always read analogous read values as 800~900 when there is not any object in front of sensor and I read 1022-1023 values when there is an object. After RC curcuit , I see values exactly "0" when there is not any object. So I understand that 800~900 values were noise of my circuit. Your circuit looks very good to obtain a clean signal. I want to try it. I just want to ask about interrupts. If I use interrup method then I will have faster results(I understood such because of your last sentence)

Comment: @Murat - yep, you will have faster results because the interrupt triggers immediately, also if you insure the `flag` is what determines if code runs or not in the loop you pick up stuff even quicker.

Comment: thanks for great ideas. Your answer is enough good. I hope it will help everybody whohas similiar problems

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your code that's causing the slowdown, especially that while loop (already nested within loop()). It could also be the ethernet but I doubt it.

Try this. Use a flag to determine whether or not an object was previously detected so you don't have to write a nested while loop.

```
int objDetected = 0;    // flag
int detection = 1020;   // detection threshold

void loop()
{
    dummy=0;  
    dummy=SensorControl2();
    if (dummy>0) {
    //Send data to SQL
    }
}

int SensorControl2()
{
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

if (sensorValue > detection) {
    // Sensor senses something for the first time, sets flag
    if (objDetected == 0) {
        Serial.println("object detected");
        objDetected = 1;
        return MachineID;
    }
    // Sensor senses something but object is still there
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
// There is no object detected, reset the flag
else {
    objDetected = 0;
}
```

Comment: you didn't show how should i use this flag in loop(). Or i should ask such, may be it will prevent complexity of main loop but i think it will not solve my main problem. Am i right?

Comment: May be this info can give some information. I read 900-970 values when there is not any item in front of sensor and vice versa i read 1020-1023 values. I don't use any resistor or another electronic component with this Photoelectric sensor and i connect it directly to arduino (+5V (Brown), Ground (Blue) and A2 (White)). May be voltage drop is not enough fast? I started to think to use resistor or capacitor to solve this issue. Here is its Specifications :
Resp time 
Under light received condition:20 μs or less
Under light interrupted condition:100 μs or less
(Response frequency:1 kHz or more)

Comment: You don't have to use the flag in loop(). It's a global variable that is manipulated by SensorControl2().

Comment: I tried your code but it detects 100-150 item at a second..